# Replacing all attachment links in post with media file link

Tags: posts, attachments, media

I'm working on a Wordpress site, where all images inside posts are linking to the corresponding attachment pages. I want to use a lightbox but obviously this would require changing all the links back to the media files directly (e.g. xyz.jpg).

The site has a significant number of posts and images so it would be impossible to do this manually.

Does anyone know of solution that would simply replace - in bulk - all of the image links to link to the media file, instead of the attachment page?

Answer (score 2):

I found a [nice snippet at this site](http://www.digitalmgmt.com/adding-link-file-wordpress-gallery-shortcode/) for your `functions.php` that does the trick:

```
 add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'file_gallery_shortcode' ); 

 function file_gallery_shortcode( $atts ) {
      $atts['link'] = 'file';
      return gallery_shortcode( $atts );
 }
```

I'd actually been looking unsuccessfully for the same thing, so I'm glad you asked.

Comment: Thank you, nice trick to override the gallery shortcode. But this would only work for images embedded in a gallery, though. I would need it to happen for all images in posts.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm looking for it too!