# bulk change of image setting "link to" to "link to: image url "

Tags: plugins, php, functions, images

i want every image present on my wordpress site with setting "link to: none" or "link to: post url" became in "link to :image url"

ho make this for old post and for new post ?

i tried this code in function.php of my theme but not work :

```
function wpb_imagelink_setup() {
    $image_set = get_option( 'image_default_link_type' );


        update_option('image_default_link_type', 'file');

}
add_action('admin_init', 'wpb_imagelink_setup', 10);
```

or

```
function wpb_imagelink_setup() {
    $image_set = get_option( 'image_default_link_type' );


        update_option('image_default_link_type', 'image url');

}
add_action('admin_init', 'wpb_imagelink_setup', 10);
```

**attention:** this for photo also  with external URL

http://postimg.org/image/msymf73zp/

Comment: It may be possible bulk changing the "link to" setting in the admin using a search and replace plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/. Obviously back-up your database first.

Comment: And what Replace ?

Comment: Hold off on modifying the database for now. Try configuring the wp-admin options page first. E.g. http://yoursite/wp-admin/options.php Read this for full instructions: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/make-image-attachments-default-link-to-original-image?replies=4#post-1706252 and failing that, try this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/image-link-url-default-none?replies=8#post-1850161. This should remedy the required default settings for new posts. Trial it and we can resume looking at options for existing (old) posts.

Comment: Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/default-image-link/

Comment: @Clarus : the setting in options.php work only for new post, i want also for old post

Comment: Also the plugin work only for new post

Comment: Then not work with external images " Insert from URL"

Comment: Best I could find: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141570/replacing-all-attachment-links-in-post-with-media-file-link but no good. Browse the post_content column of the wp_posts table and find one of your old posts. Copy an example of the image element you want to change. Start a question on StackOverflow. Paste the copied image element. Beneath it paste how it should be. Ask for query that will bulk replace all image elements. Position the question as a SQL question, not a WordPress question.

Comment: Here's an example of the SQL replace function: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/migrating-wordpress-inmotion-hosting/correct-image-links It's worth adding to your new question so that the answerer has something to model the question off of.